# Was prophet Noah (PBUH) a prophet for Indian people?

Tags: history, prophet-nuh

I have just read a post ([Lost Prophets of Hinduism and India](https://khurshidimam.blogspot.in/2013/05/lost-prophets-of-hinduism-and-india.html)) and there are several scriptures in Hinduism which talk about the great flood (as mentioned in Quran and Injeel) and story is almost same but with a huge detail in Hinduism (in Matsya puran) and as mentioned in Quran [Surat Hud](https://quran.com/11) that people of Noah believe in discrimination and also mentioned that people used to worship idols, both conditions apply to Hindus and they had Vedas whose text matches with Quran very much like :-

> Yajurveda 40.1
>   This entire world is embedded within and managed by the One and Only One Ishwar. Never dare do any injustice or desire riches through unjust means. Instead, follow the righteous path and enjoy His bliss. After all, He alone is source of all bliss!
>
> Rigveda 10.48.5
>   Ishwar enlightens the entire world. He is undefeated and undying. He is the creator of the world. All souls should seek bliss through seeking knowledge and acting thereupon. They should never shun the friendship of Ishwar
>
> Rigveda 10.49.1
>   Ishwar alone provides true knowledge to truth seekers. He alone is promoter of knowledge and motivates virtuous people into noble actions to seek bliss. He alone is the creator and manager of the world. Hence never worship anyone else except one and only Ishwar
>
> Atharvaveda 10.7.38
>   Ishwar alone is greatest and worth being worshipped. He is the source of all knowledge and activities.

And as per hadith's first revelation that was revealed to Prophet Noah and the oldest book on the earth which was regarded to be God's word is Vedas (the part which matches with Quran, I agree, but most parts match) and who wrote the Veda is still unknown and bhavishya puran also mention "Nuh" name

Edit:

Also Muhammad (SAW) (PBUH) MENTIONED that on day of judgement Allah (SWT) will also ask prophet that you delivered message than Noah will reply "Yes and than Allah (SWT) will ask the community of Noah has Nuh delivered his message and they will say no "no prophet come to us" indicating that people of Noah (AS) does not even know about their messenger and the same is the case with Hindus they have Vedas but who written that is unknown?

Comment: The greate flood was also mentioned in the Babylonian epic of  Athra-Hasis and adapted in the epic of Gilgamesh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epic_of_Gilgamesh I  wonder if this question really belongs here rather than to history.SE.

Comment: I want some more hints from Quran and hadith about prophet Noah  read this :- http://khurshidimam.blogspot.in/2013/05/lost-prophets-of-hinduism-and-india.html?m=1

Comment: I think this should be covered here https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42937/when-did-noah-live/42948#42948

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that many cultures seem to have flood stories is because at the time of Nuh (AS), all of humanity was in one city. So, this story gets passed down, so that many cultures that spread out afterwards remember such a story although corrupted.

This is the dua made by Nuh (AS) for the destruction of the disbelievers of the time:

> وَقَالَ نُوحٌ رَّبِّ لَا تَذَرْ عَلَى الْأَرْضِ مِنَ الْكَافِرِينَ دَيَّارًا - 71:26
>
> And Nuh said, "My Lord, do not leave upon the earth from among the disbelievers an inhabitant.

Nuh (AS) asks Allah to destroy every single disbeliever on Earth, and he would not ask for the destruction of all disbelievers if he wasn't sent to all disbelievers meaning he was sent to all mankind of the time.

Additionally, this means every single persons ancestor experienced the flood because the only people saved were the ones on the Ark. They, then, spread out in the land and took their stories with them, creating myths and legends in public memory of a giant flood everywhere.

To answer the question about whether the flood happened in India:

> Narrated Ibn Abbas: **All the idols which were worshiped by the people of Noah were worshiped by the Arabs later on.** As for the **idol Wadd**, it was worshiped by the tribe of Kalb at Daumat-al-Jandal; **Suwa was the idol** of (the tribe of) Hudhail; **Yaghouth** was worshiped by (the tribe of) Murad and then by Bani Ghutaif at Al-Jurf near Saba; **Yauq** was the idol of Hamdan, and **Nasr** was the idol of Himyar, the branch of Dhi-al-Kala. The names (of the idols) formerly belonged to some pious men of the people of Noah, and when they died Satan inspired their people to (prepare and place idols at the places where they used to sit, and to call those idols by their names. The people did so, but the idols were not worshiped till those people (who initiated them) had died and the origin of the idols had become obscure, whereupon people began worshiping them. (Bukhari)

Those are the names of the idols worshiped by the people of Nuh (AS). Those are not found anywhere in India today nor do we have any history of worship of such idols. Additionally, all the names sound linguistically semetic in nature, and don't look much like Indo-European names.

So, to answer your question, No. The flood did not happen in India, but the Hindu people (and many others) remember it because technically all civilizations' ancestors experienced the flood.

Comment: Than why so many Hindu scriptures mention so much about Noah (PBUH) and how oldest relevation Veda come in existence ? And where does the Noah (PBUH) relevation gone ? Look this verse :-"O my tribe! Allah, who is the Creator of the earth and the sky, will bring torture on you. What do you rely on when His wrath hits you? Do you have any place to take refuge in? Everywhere belongs to Allah. If He has decided to send you His wrath, you will not be able to escape it. No force can stop His wrath."                                 There was a tribe of idol worshipers prophet Nuh was sent for them.

Comment: Prophet Nuh (PBUH) was not for all humanity

Comment: The Prophet Nuh was sent for all of humanity due to a technicality. He was sent in an early time of human history. Only a few generations after Adam (AS). Because at his time there **was** only one city. And that was the city he was sent to. Thus all of humanity.

Comment: @Anonykous It was by a technicality that Nuh (AS) was sent to all of humanity.

Comment: According to Muslim scholars Adam (AS) landed in India

Comment: "at the time of Nuh (AS), all of humanity was in one city" - Please provide references for this.

Comment: @Kilise . The Ayah is my proof. Why would the flood destroy all disbelievers if Nuh (AS) wasn't sent to all disbelievers? After all, Allah doesn't punish a nation until a prophet is sent to them.

Comment: @Anonykous . Where Adam (AS) landed is a different thing. And if you read the whole story of that, you would know that he did not stay there. He travelled to find his wife who landed somwhere else (not in India).

Comment: @TheZ There are different opinions wether the flood was global or local, see [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7424/15201), the traditional view is that it was global. That said, it doesn't dissmiss the fact that there are valid interpretations saying it was local. Anyway, if the flood was global, that in itself doesn't prove that all humanity was in one city, and I know of no references of that statemen. Please provide one if you think there is. If you just made a deduction of that all disbelievers where drowned, therefore they all lived in one city, then please add that to the answer.

Comment: @Kilise . I made the deduction that all disbelievers were drowned thus Nuh (AS) was sent to all disbelievers.

Comment: It logically follows considering the travelling speed of the time that they lived in a relatively small area if Nuh (AS) was to give them all the message

Comment: I'm not even sure horses were tamed yet.

Comment: Just to add an example of the quoted verse you added (71:26) where it says  "الْأَرْضِ", the word ard which is translated to earth here, could also mean land/country, as it does in several other verses, see [5:33](https://quran.com/5/33) and [17:76](https://quran.com/17/76), [17:103](https://quran.com/17/106) . Anyway there are different opinions in this matter, both with valid evidences according to ones method of interpretation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73849/discussion-between-the-z-and-kilise).

Comment: @Anon  I added a hadith to show why it couldn't have been in India.