# Was Prophet Noah sent for all humanity at his time?

Tags: history, prophet-nuh

We know that Prophet Muhammed was sent for all humanity & jinns from his time till the Day of Judgement.

But I'd like to verify the claim in one of the answers for the below question:

[https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46232/was-prophet-noah-pbuh-a-prophet-for-indian-people](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46232/was-prophet-noah-pbuh-a-prophet-for-indian-people?rq=1)

i.e **Was Prophet Noah sent for all humanity that existed at his time?**

Comment: Doesn't the answer itself explain the reasoning behind their claim? I don't think people can provide anything much different than the evidence already given.

Comment: @TheZ  Tbh the reasoning given  in the answer is inconclusive. Hence my query.